# How to extract lines between two patterns using variable

Tags: awk

```
$ cat /tmp/zfssa_check_raw.log
====== aps_akd_service_offline.output ======
WARN: akd service state is online
====== aps_akd_service_offline.result:1 ======
```

With fixed pattern strings, it works as expected.

```
$ awk '/aps_akd_service_offline.output/{flag=1;next}/aps_akd_service_offline.result/{flag=0}flag' /tmp/zfssa_check_raw.log
WARN: akd service state is online
```

But when I use a and b variable to represent the flexible pattern,
it displayed nothing. I do not know why, could someone help here?

```
$ awk -v a="aps_akd_service_offline.output" -v b="aps_akd_service_offline.result" '/a/{flag=1;next}/b/{flag=0}flag' /tmp/zfssa_check_raw.log

$ a="aps_akd_service_offline.output"
$ b="aps_akd_service_offline.result"

$ awk -va="${a}" -vb="${b}" '/a/{flag=1;next}/b/{flag=0}flag' /tmp/zfssa_check_raw.log
```

Comment: format your question to make it readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a regex match with a variable use the `~` operator:

```
awk -v a="aps_akd_service_offline.output" -v b="aps_akd_service_offline.result" \
            '$0 ~ a {flag=1;next} $0 ~ b {flag=0}flag' /tmp/zfssa_check_raw.log
```